# keyword argument or workaround for left join so values of columns are replaced with those of another DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, join, error-handling, julia, left-join

What is a keyword argument or a workaround for joining DataFrames `x` and `y` below in `leftjoin!()` so that the values of column `d` within `x` are replaced with those of `d` within `y` instead of returning an error?

```
using DataFrames
x=DataFrame(a=[1,2,3],b=[4,5,6],c=[7,20,9],d=[nothing,99,nothing])
y=DataFrame(a=[1,2,3],b=[4,5,6],c=[7,8,9],d=[10,11,12])
leftjoin!(x,y,on=[:a,:b,:c]) # returns error
```

Desired output:

```
3×4 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b      c      d
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │     1      4      7     10
   2 │     2      5     20     99
   3 │     3      6      9     12
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select(
  leftjoin!(x,y,on=[:a,:b,:c]; makeunique=true),
  Not(r"d"),:d_1 => identity => :d)
```

The `d` column is not perfect as it picked up a `Missing` type.

Another option:

```
combine(
  groupby(vcat(x,y),[:a,:b,:c]),
  :d => splat(something) =>:d)
```

Fixing the first method:

```
select(
  leftjoin(x,y,on=[:a,:b,:c]; makeunique=true),
  Not(r"d"),r"d" => ByRow(something) => :d)
```

Comment: @wanderinganon I've added a fix at the bottom of the answer, which should work. In the change you made to the question, edit the `Nothing` to `nothing` (the former is a type, the latter is a value).

Answer (score 0):

```
select(
    leftjoin(x, y, on=[:a, :b], makeunique=true), 
    :a, :b, ([col, "$(col)_1"] => ByRow(something) => col for col in ("c", "d"))...
)
```